# cron uid:gui for every username

Tags: cron, centos-6, uid

So in the nutshell :

There was user `John` with `502:502`.

After i deleted `John` and recreated him, his `UID:GID` changed to `504:504`.

`Cronjobs` are still running under the `John`'s crontab, but when the `cronjobs` are happening they are writing some files into `/home/John` in the name of `502:502`.

It is quite a mess, and I am not sure what would be the easier way to solve it, either change current `John`'s `uid` and `gid` to `502:502` - which could cause more problems with files the user was working since.
But I was thinking that going somewhere to cron config and changing `John`'s `uid:gid` from `502:502` to `504:504` there, inside cron.

Looked all over the place, but can not find it. Any ideas ?

EDIT: I am on CentOS 6

Comment: Sounds like you're on a Mac, but you should give your operating system information explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in `/var/spool/cron` for the user crontabs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a name service caching daemon running on your system, try to restart it. Typical names contain something like nscd.

You can also check `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/John` (or the equivalent file) and make sure that the file has the correct permissions. Otherwise it may help to restart cron.